# How to safe change the type of a variable intellij?

Tags: java, variables, intellij-idea, types, intellij-14

Suppose I have a class like this.

```
Public class MyClass{
    private String id;

    public Myclass(String id){
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getId(){
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id){
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

And suddenly I want to change the `type of id` into `Integer`. Is there a way to do that with **intellij** without breaking usages?

Comment: may you give details of `safe change`?  I can't figure out what you expected for

Comment: I want to change the type of variable 'id' from String to Integer with one time operation, without changing usages one by one.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Highlight the type of field and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>

or

Highlight the type of field, `Right-Click -> Refactor -> Type migration`

or

Highlight the type of field, `Menu -> Refactor -> Type migration`